# Random forest regression - cumulative MSE?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I am new to Random Forests and I have a question about regression. I am using R package randomForests to calculate RF models.

My final goal is to select sets of variables important for prediction of a continuous trait, and so I am calculating a model, then I remove the variable with lowest mean decrease in accuracy, and I calculate a new model, and so on. This worked with RF classification, and I compared the models using the OOB errors from prediction (training set), development and validation data sets. Now with regression I want to compare the models based on %variation explained and MSE.

I was evaluating the results for MSE and %var explained, and I get exactly the same results when calculating manually using the prediction from `model$predicted`. But when I do `model$mse`, the value presented corresponds to the value of MSE for the last tree calculated, and the same happens for % var explained.

As an example you can try this code in R:

```
library(randomForest)
data("iris")
head(iris)

TrainingX<-iris[1:100,2:4] #creating training set - X matrix
TrainingY<-iris[1:100,1]  #creating training set - Y vector

TestingX<-iris[101:150,2:4]  #creating test set - X matrix
TestingY<-iris[101:150,1]  #creating test set - Y vector

set.seed(2)

model<-randomForest(x=TrainingX, y= TrainingY, ntree=500, #calculating model
                    xtest = TestingX, ytest = TestingY)

#for prediction (training set)

pred<-model$predicted

meanY<-sum(TrainingY)/length(TrainingY)

varpY<-sum((TrainingY-meanY)^2)/length(TrainingY)

mseY<-sum((TrainingY-pred)^2)/length(TrainingY)

r2<-(1-(mseY/varpY))*100

#for testing (test set)

pred_2<-model$test$predicted

meanY_2<-sum(TestingY)/length(TestingY)

varpY_2<-sum((TestingY-meanY_2)^2)/length(TestingY)

mseY_2<-sum((TestingY-pred_2)^2)/length(TestingY)

r2_2<-(1-(mseY_2/varpY_2))*100

training_set_mse<-c(model$mse[500], mseY)
training_set_rsq<-c(model$rsq[500]*100, r2)
testing_set_mse<-c(model$test$mse[500],mseY_2)
testing_set_rsq<-c(model$test$rsq[500]*100, r2_2)

c<-cbind(training_set_mse,training_set_rsq,testing_set_mse, testing_set_rsq)
rownames(c)<-c("last tree", "by hand")
c
model
```

As a result after running this code you will obtain a table containing values for MSE and %var explaines (also called rsq). The first line is called "last tree" and contains the values of MSE and %var explained for the 500th tree in the forest. The second line is called "by hand" and it contains results calculated in R based on the vectors `model$predicted` and `model$test$predicted`.

So, my questions are:

1- Are the predictions of the trees somehow cumulative? Or are they independent from each other? (I thought they were independent)

2- Is the last tree to be considered as an average of all the others?

3- Why are MSE and %var explained of the RF model (presented in the main board when you call `model`) the same as the ones from the 500th tree (see first line of table)? Do the vectors `model$mse` or `model$rsq` contain cumulative values?

After the last edit I found this post from Andy Liaw (one of the creators of the package) that says that MSE and %var explained are in fact cumulative!: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-April/049943.html.

Comment: Typical question for SO sistersite stats [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: For the next time, please spend a minute to learn how to properly format your code; be sure also to always include the relevant library imports (both done for you this time). Kudos for the reproducible example though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand what your issue is; I'll give it a try nevertheless...

> 1- Are the predictions of the trees somehow cumulative? Or are they
>   independent from each other? (I thought they were independent)

You thought correctly; the trees are fit independently of each other, hence their predictions are indeed independent. In fact, this is a crucial advantage of RF models, since it allows for parallel implementations.

> 2- Is the last tree to be considered as an average of all the others?

**No**; as clarified above, *all* trees are independent.

> 3- If each tree gets a prediction, how can I get the matrix with all the trees, since what I need is the MSE and % var explained for the forest?

Here is where what you ask starts being really unclear, given your code above; the MSE and r2 you say you need are exactly what you are already computing in `mseY` and `r2`:

```
mseY
[1] 0.1232342

r2
[1] 81.90718
```

which, unsurpizingly, are the very same values reported by `model`:

```
model
# result:

Call:
 randomForest(x = TrainingX, y = TrainingY, ntree = 500) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 1

          Mean of squared residuals: 0.1232342
                    % Var explained: 81.91
```

so I'm not sure I can really see your issue, or what these values have to do with the "matrix with all the trees"...

> But when I do `model$mse`, the value presented corresponds to the value
>   of MSE for the last tree calculated, and the same happens for % var
>   explained.

<s>Most certainly **not**: `model$mse` is a vector of length equal to the number of trees (here 500), containing the MSE for each individual tree;</s> (see UPDATE below) I have never seen any use for this in practice (similarly for `model$rsq`):

```
length(model$mse)
[1] 500

length(model$rsq)
[1] 500
```

**UPDATE**: Kudos to the OP herself (see comments), who discovered that the quantities in `model$mse` and `model$rsq` are indeed *cumulative* (!); from an old (2004) thread by package maintainer Andy Liaw, [Extracting the MSE and % Variance from RandomForest](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-April/049943.html):

> Several ways:
>
> 1. Read ?randomForest, especially the `Value' section.
> 2. Look at str(myforest.rf).
> 3. Look at print.randomForest.
>
> If the forest has 100 trees, then the mse and rsq are vectors with 100
>   elements each, the i-th element being the mse (or rsq) of the forest
>   consisting of the first i trees.  So the last element is the mse (or
>   rsq) of the whole forest.

Comment: Many thanks for the help. About the model$mse and model$rsq, I know I get a vector of length equal to the number of trees in the forest, but if you check model$mse[500] or model$rsq[500] (following the example in the original question), you will see that the resuts are the same as the ones give in the "main board of results", so 0.1232342 and 81.91 respectively. This is the main point of my confusion: is the model$predicted the last tree or the average of the trees? I am sorry if I am being repetitive. Anyway, I will try to edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @JoanaLima it might be the case that `model$mse` reports stuff cumulatively (underneath, the subject R package still uses the original Fortran code of Breiman & Cutler, and who knows what they *then* thought it would be important - OOB error, for example, has never found any serious use in practice); as I said, I have been using RF since 2012, and I have **never** seen any use for this stuff in practice. Nevertheless, the rest of the answer (i.e. your 3 questions, which arguably is the important part) holds...

Comment: @JoanaLima I would kindly suggest you accept this answer and possibly open a new one, focused exactly on `model$mse`, if you still have concerns (as you see, this one is already closed as too broad).

Comment: Thanks. They are important for my case because I want to select the group of variables that leads to higher %variance explained. The problem here is that now I am not sure if the vector from model$predicted is the prediction of the forest or only of the last tree, or if, as you suggest, the MSE and %var explained are cumulative. The OOB error, as I understand has also been used to do comparison of groups of variables, and selection of the "best" variables. Yes, I will do that. Thanks!

Comment: @JoanaLima still, cannot see why you need the `model$mse` for that, when you can simply calculate the *forest* MSE (as you actually do) and be free of doubt... As I said, your basic 3 questions have been arguably answered

Comment: the model MSE is calculated based on the prediction from model$predicted, but I am not sure if this corresponds to the prediction of the forest or to the last tree predicted. I am going to try also prediction of an external dataset and compare results and come back to post a new question. Many thanks for all the help!

Comment: @JoanaLima great job! But as I said, it is highly doubtful that this stuff is of any real use (*cumulative* MSE? why?). At least it confirms your suspicions... I'll update the answer to reflect this (unfortunately the question is now closed, and you cannot add this yourself as an answer...)

Comment: thank for all the help! I read the rules about posting, and apparently it is on hold, now I edited so it goes again for review. I still don't understand the R2 differences though. I need this because I have more than 1000 X variables, so I calculate one model including all variables, remove the worst MDA variable and do a new model and so on until I have only one X variable. In the end I compare the models and select the group of variables leading to higher %var explained and use these variables in a different analyses to validate the selection (PLS or correlation network).

Comment: @JoanaLima I kindly suggest you **forget** this question and move on with your new one(s)! In any case, arguably you now know much more than before asking, and the question itself is now obsolete - go on & open a new one, it's even free! ;)